# "Multiplying" Clebsch-Gordan series

Tags: rt.representation-theory

Assume you have a Lie algebra $G$ and a Clebsch-Gordan series $A\bigotimes{B}=C\bigoplus{D}\bigoplus...$
Assume you have a Lie algebra $g$ and a Clebsch-Gordan series $a\bigotimes{b}=c\bigoplus{d}\bigoplus...$
Now consider the direct sum $G+g$ and their irreps $(A,a)$ and $(B,b)$.
$(A,a)\bigotimes{(B,b)}=(C,c)\bigoplus{(C,d)}\bigoplus{(D,c)}\bigoplus...$ or what?
At least if $G=g$ it can't work with the distributive law that nicely since then some vector spaces coincide. (If you want to make me *very* happy, use the adjoint of $G=A_2$ as example - it costed me months to realize it's not $(11,11)$ but $(00,11)+(11,00)$. Or such. That would be my bonus question - is the adjoint of $G+g$ something like $(E,a)+(A,e)$ with $E,e$ the trivial and $A,a$ the adjoint irreps?)

Comment: I am pretty sure that the distributive law works. What do you mean by some spaces coinciding? The sum is direct, so the Lie subalgebras $G$ and $g$ are isomorphic but distinct, and a representation can distinguish the action of $G$ on it from the action of $g$ on it. (I am assuming that the Clebsch-Gordan series is the decomposition of a tensor product of two irreps in a direct sum of irreps.)

Comment: And the answer to your bonus question is "yes" -- the action of $G+g$ on $G+g$ is componentwise Lie bracketing, so that the subspace $G$ is isomorphic to the representation $(A, e)$, and the subspace $g$ is isomorphic to the representation $(E, a)$.

Comment: @Darij: THX. Here is an example the intuitive law can't work when G=g. SU2=A1 defining dimension already works. (I label by dimension, not J.) 2*2=1+3. (2,2)*(2,2)=1+3+3+9 (so far, so good). (2,2,2)*(2,2,2)=1+9+27+27. With simple distributive law, you would get eight terms! (But (1,1,3),(1,3,1),(3,1,1) somehow fall together, and so do (1,3,3) etc., which explains the dimensions. At least they do for the span of the clebsch - the R matrix fulfils a cubic equation and that's what relevant to me.)

Comment: How do you get  (2,2,2)*(2,2,2)=1+9+27+27 ?

Comment: By reading it somewhere :-) Myself, I of course would have used the naive distributive law. But here is an even more striking example from 3A1: Since it's on the Vogel plane and a member of the quarternion series, one just needs to look up the relevant (Westbury) paper to get adjoint^2: 9^2=1+9+2+15+27+27. Dissecting this: 9 is 113+131+311, 15 is 115+151+511, 1 is 111, 2 is the other two 111+111 (from 113*113), 27 is 133+313+331 (from 113*113), other 27 is 133+313+331 (from 113*131). The distributive law gives the building blocks, but "clustering" of irreps is completely wacky.

Comment: Thus: 2A2(16)^2=(1,8+8,1)^2=(1,8)^2+(8,1)^2+2*(1,8)*(8,1)=(1,1)+(1,8)+(1,8)+(1,10)+(1,10)+(1,27)+(1,1)+(8,1)+(8,1)+(10,1)+(10,1)+(27,1)+(8,8)+(8,8). Those are the blocks, but which must be "clustered" to get the right dimensions?

Comment: I don't get it -- why are you clustering irreps? The tensor product of an irrep of $\mathfrak g$ with an irrep of $\mathfrak h$ is an irrep of $\mathfrak g \oplus \mathfrak h$.

Comment: The span (?) of the vector space of $A\bigotimes{B}$ doesn't come out right otherwise! OK, you have then 8 irreps of (2,2,2)*(2,2,2) (I have to trust you on that) but still, it's vector space needs only four basis vectors to build the R matrix. (Is the span 8 nevertheless?) In all dimension formulas I know, the "clustered" irreps appear.

Comment: I fear we're talking way too different languages to understand each other; I don't even see where an R-matrix would appear here (aren't these for when you want to define a nonstandard braiding structure on tensor products?), and I don't understand what "span" means for you :(

Comment: You're right. Problem is I have no formal education in higher math and usually don't even know the correct terms. In any case, you can peek into "Birdtracks" by Cvitanovic (he's kind of a maverick too, but at least he knows the math :-) - on p. 232 of his "Group Theory" pdf I found the 8^2=1+9+27+27. The table header lists "Rep" so it's well possible that his vector spaces are built from *several* irreps.

Comment: Are you talking about the two 27's in Table 20.3? I don't see how they have much to do with (2,2,2)*(2,2,2) and where the 1 and 9 should be. (I wish I could say I understand the notation in Cvitanovic...)

Comment: Yup, those. And after perusing his opus magnum for three years or so I understand it *a bit* :-) But we have digressed so much that we better take this issue to PM... (reddmannatchemiedotuni-hamburgdotde)